# OneToMany relationship in EntityProxy in RequestFactory GWT

Tags: java, gwt, requestfactory

I have a problem with EntityProxies in RequestFactory.

```
@ProxyFor(value=Day.class, locator = DayLocator.class)
public interface DayProxy extends EntityProxy{

      List<OrganizerEntryProxy> getEntries();
      void setEntries(List<OrganizerEntryProxy> entries);
      etc...
}
```

Entity:

```
public class Day implements Serializable {

    private List<OrganizerEntry> entries;
        etc...

        public List<OrganizerEntry> getEntries(){
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(entries);
    }

    public void  setEntries(List<OrganizerEntry> entries){
        this.entries = entries;
    }
        etc....
}
```

`OrganizerEntryProxy` is `EntityProxy` not `ValueProxy`.

Now, when in service, I send a `Day`  instance to the client with `OrganizerEntry` List containing `OrganizerEntry` entities. When it is received at the client `DayProxy.getEntries()` returns null.  Retrieving `OrganizerEntity` alone works allright.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hah, mystery unveiled. It was rather basic problem. I had to add `.with("entries").fire(.`. to the call. It seems stupid but all the information I had was from http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory.html and some HelloWorld internet  examples.  Is there more detailed documentation to RequestFactory?

Comment: `.with()` is explained in this doc (see [here](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory.html#relationships)); you can have a look at my blog otherwise: http://blog.ltgt.net, and https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/RequestFactoryMovingParts

Comment: Thanks. Hm I wonder what other things I must have overlooked there. So should I take it that http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory.html  is the only official documentation for RequestFactory ?

Comment: Yes; plus the "moving parts" wiki page (and possibly one other page). At least for now…